# Showing a bitmap url with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, bitmapfactory

Hi I have a code which is not complete.

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.AsyckTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    Button button;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LoadBitmap load = new LoadBitmap();
                load.execute("");
            }
        });
    }

    public class LoadBitmap extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
 Bitmap b;
            try {
                b= BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(params[0]).getContent());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            if (bitmap !=null){

            }else {

            }
            pd.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

My question is where should I put the url ,or what else should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either pass the url as parameter in async task constructor or pass it in the execute function.

The first way is more verbose and is a general dependency injection and parameter passing method that works on all classes and objects, the second way is specific to async task class provided by Android framework.

**Passing url in constructor:**

```
public class LoadBitmap extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private String mUrl;

    public LoadBitmap(String url) {
        mUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        final String url = mUrl;
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
LoadBitmap loadBitmap = new LoadBitmap("http://www.example.com/path/to/image");
loadBitmap.execute();
```

**Passing parameters in execute method:**

```
public class LoadBitmap extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (params.length == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You should pass me a url!!");
        final String url = params[0];
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

And it can be used in this way:

```
LoadBitmap loadBitmap = new LoadBitmap();
loadBitmap.execute("http://www.example.com/path/to/image");
```

In your code, instead of returning `null`, you should return `b`. That bitmap then is passed to `onPostExecute`, there you can do whatever you want to that bitmap, for example you can display it inside your `ImageView`.

```
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        Bitmap b = null;
        try {
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(params[0]).getContent());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return b;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        if (bitmap !=null){
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        pd.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: @Sahand.Setoodeh خواهش می‌کنم :)

Comment: @Sahand.Setoodeh بله. خب بهترین سایت سوال و جوابه :-) فک کنم چت تو کامنتا مشکل داشته باشه به خصوص که فارسی مینویسیم و نمی‌فهمن قضیه چیه :))

Answer (score 0):

I think First you read a bit more about asynk Task.

load.execute("");

> instead of passing an empty String, you have to pass the url

If you want to show image with your Button Click.

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LoadBitmap load = new LoadBitmap();
                load.execute("http://stackoverflow.com/");// Here is Url 
            }
        });
```

Other Wise put this snippet of code in OnCreate

```
LoadBitmap load = new LoadBitmap();
                    load.execute("http://stackoverflow.com/");// Here is Url
```

**Update**

You Can use It In This Way

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        if (bitmap !=null){



     ImageView mImg;
mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.(your xml img id));
mImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }else {

        }
        pd.dismiss();
    }
```

Put this code in OnPostExecute method of Asynktask

Comment: Thanks but where should I use Bitmap b? Please! it is a project that has to be done.

Comment: You can use in ImageView